# Passing gclid to _trackEvent

Tags: google-analytics

I am using _trackEvent to record events in Google Analytics, and it appears to work fine.

I am doing something like this:

```
_gaq_push(['_trackEvent', 'Chat', 'Male',
        'www.somesite.co.uk/?gclid=CNHvuPiijrUCFQsGnQodpjsA9w']);
```

Now, I see the URL and gclid appear in the label field in Google Analytics, however what I really want to happen is for it to interpret the gclid and populate the keywords section in GA.

Is this possible? How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here but gclid is something that is not publicly documented. If you really want to fill in the campaign information, you should try and use the APIs described [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCampaigns#customCampaignTracking) or do something like [this](http://blog.kissmetrics.com/how-to-use-utm-parameters/).

Comment: From one page, I am trying to send to analytics an action, a label, and a gclid, so that in GA I can see all of the keywords and PCC info that is determined from the gclid.

Comment: hmm. I am not sure if that is how it works. anything that you pass into trackEvent will most likely be considered as opaque strings. There is no reason for Google to parse the event label as URL. Are you sure this is a supported and/or a documented behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Link your adwords account to your google analytics account and the gclid will be resolved automatically. Manually resolving the gclid ist not possible.

Update: Sorry, I've only just seen that you are talking about events. So no, that is not possible - the proper way is to build segments with your keywords and to see which events apply to that segment (or the other way around, depending on what you are doing).